# Is there a way around to create TypeScript classes in closures?

Tags: class, typescript, closures, javascript-namespaces

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA's File Watcher to automatically compile the TypeScript files, but for some reason it's not liking classes defined within blocks / function closures:

[image]

Is there a way around this without having to move everything to the top-level / global scope?

Answer (score 2):

Using the following code in TypeScript results in practically the same JavaScript that you appear to be aiming for...

```
namespace MY_NAMESPACE {
    export class AssetService {

    }
}
```

Resulting code:

```
var MY_NAMESPACE;
(function (MY_NAMESPACE) {
    var AssetService = (function () {
        function AssetService() {
        }
        return AssetService;
    }());
    MY_NAMESPACE.AssetService = AssetService;
})(MY_NAMESPACE || (MY_NAMESPACE = {}));
```

If you want to *really* reduce the scope, switch to external modules (AKA "modules" these days).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't export the class from the module/file, it won't be visible globally, i.e. there's no reason to enclose class definitions in function scopes.

More about modules in TS: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: True, but what if there's an object in the same scope that stores a reference to the class, then it gets exposed to the global scope right? (see screenshot in question)

Comment: (cont.) Ah I think I see what you're saying now. It's pointless to store a reference to the class the way I have it setup, that work is done by defining it in a module, basically?

Comment: Correct, you're still thinking in terms of JS, when you should think about how TS (and ES6 for that matter) works.